# Get x,y values for a data point from plot

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, core-plot

How can I get x,y values for a datapoint (symbol) visible on plot ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGCRU.png

I've tried to use a `CPTPlotSpaceDelegate` method :`- (void)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space didChangePlotRangeForCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate` but I can't get right values for x,y axes. So far I did this

```
- (void)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space didChangePlotRangeForCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)space;
    NSLog(@"x= %f", plotSpace.xRange.locationDouble);
    NSLog(@"y= %f", plotSpace.yRange.locationDouble);

    // If point is in the middle of plot, save it's yRange value
    if (plotSpace.xRange.locationDouble == mPlotSpace.xRange.midPointDouble) {
        mSelectedPoint = plotSpace.yRange.locationDouble;
    }

    [mLinePlot reloadData];

}
```

but none of NSLogs print correct values.

Comment: You're logging the new starting locations of the plot space after a change to the `xRange` or `yRange` (check the `coordinate` parameter to see which one changed). It's not clear from the question what x- and y- values you're looking for.

Comment: @EricSkroch look at the image maybe it will be more clear

Comment: Do you want the coordinates of one of the data points? As data values or in view coordinates? Which data point?

Comment: @EricSkroch Yes, I need coordinates of VISIBLE data points as data values

Answer (score 0):

Plot ranges have methods to check if a given value falls within the range:

```
-(BOOL)contains:(NSDecimal)number;
-(BOOL)containsDouble:(double)number;
-(BOOL)containsNumber:(NSNumber *)number;
```

Use one of these methods on the `xRange` and `yRange` to check each of your data points. If a point passes both tests, it's visible. Otherwise, it is outside the visible plot area.